# Receiving Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN

Tags: swift, nan, cmtime

The code is for a podcasting app.

```
import AVKit

extension CMTime {
func toDisplayString() -> String {
    let totalSeconds = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(self))
    let seconds = totalSeconds % 60
    let minutes = totalSeconds / 60
    let timeFormatString = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    return timeFormatString
}
}
```

It fails when selecting a podcast to play... resulting in audio playing but the app to freeze until rebooted.

Edit: The error ocurs on line `let totalSeconds = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(self))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`CMTimeGetSeconds` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1400857-cmtimegetseconds):

> If the CMTime is invalid or indefinite, NaN is returned. If the CMTime
>   is infinite, +/- infinity is returned.

When `CMTimeGetSeconds` returns NaN or infinity, casting the return value to an `Int` will throw the Fatal Error you are seeing.

You can first check the value then return some sort of default in case it's not a valid number.

```
func toDisplayString() -> String {
    let rawSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(self)
    guard !(rawSeconds.isNaN || rawSeconds.isInfinite) else {
       return "--" // or some other default string
    }
    let totalSeconds = Int(rawSeconds)
    let seconds = totalSeconds % 60
    let minutes = totalSeconds / 60
    let timeFormatString = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    return timeFormatString
}
```

Comment: Thank you... in another question I found this, but i was implementing it in the wrong place :)

Answer (score 2):

The below code should work... basically it happens because the value that is returned by `CMTimeGetSeconds(self)` is beyond `Int` limit.

```
func toDisplayString() -> String {
        let totalSeconds:TimeInterval = TimeInterval(CMTimeGetSeconds(self))
        let seconds:TimeInterval = totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)
        let minutes:TimeInterval = totalSeconds / 60
        let timeFormatString = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
        return timeFormatString
    }
```